# Circuit Breaker does not work when a method annotated with HystrixCommand calls another method which throws exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class A {
    public String makeSomething(String ingredients){
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't Make anything");
    }
}
```

This class is realised in another class B(Spring Service) which uses makeSomething in many of its own methods by passing Ingredients. Each method in class B is annotated with HystrixCommand and a fallback has been defined for it. Here is what it looks like

```
@Service
public class B extends A {    
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "doNothing")
    public void makeTea(String ingredients){
        makeSomething(ingredients);
    }

    public void doNothing(String ingredients){
        System.out.println("Doing Nothing");
    }

}
```

Now when makeTea from class B is invoked, it inturn calls makeSomething from class A which then throws exception. This should be wrapped as HystrixRuntimeException and then fallback should be invoked. But I am seeing RunTimeException("Can't Make anything").

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, I would say, Hystrix is not enabled.

Add `@EnableHystrix` annotation to your Application class, so annotation processing is enabled.

If you have it enabled, please provide a more complete example, where the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
    @EnableHystrix is already there. Problem is something else. I have any way opened an issue with Netflix Hystrix on Github.

Comment: @SuhelKhan did you have any resolution on this also, could you share link to the github issue on this. Thanks